# VMware requirements for Ubuntu

Tags: system-installation, vmware

I am running Windows 8 on my PC.

I want to run Ubuntu on my VMware. How much RAM and HDD space is required to run it smoothly on Virtual machine.

Comment: 1 GB Ram with 10 GB HDD is enough.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your PC, you would usually want to increase the memory as much as possibles in order for it to run smoothly. As for HDD, it a minimum of 20GB is enough. You can also set the number of cores. More info on this site: http://wiki.opencog.org/w/Setting_up_Ubuntu_in_VMWare_for_Noobs